# How to update react hook when navigator/window changes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have made a hook to get navigator object with `useEffect` like this:

```js
function useNavigator () {
  const [navi, setNavi] = useState({})

  useEffect(() => {
    setNavi(navigator)
  }, [navigator])

  return navi
}
```

The problem is that the `useEffect` hook is not triggered, when the navigator is changed(I change the navigator instance in devtool). I know this should be treated as an edge case, which `navigator` should not be changing often, but how can I update the state correctly when it changes?

Answer (score 0):

React doesn't know/can keep track of navigator variable if it is not declared in component scope. It is neither part of state nor a prop.

Tracking `navigator` with a `useState()` hook will solve your problem and properly watch that change. I see that you're trying to do that in some way.

First off, you need to initialize `navi` with the `navigator` value.

`const [navi, setNavi] = useState({})`

Then you need a way to listen for navigator to change *outside* React. For example, an event listener. That event listener will be responsible for running your `setNavi`. You could add (and cleanup) the listener inside `useEffect`.

This way, if `useEffect` depends on `navi`, it will run every time after your event listener updated the `navi` value.

```
function useNavigator () {
  const [navi, setNavi] = useState(navigator)

  updateNavi() {
    setNavi(newNavigatorValue)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    // pseudocode
    addEventListener("eventThatUpdatesNavigator", updateNavi);

    return () => removeEventListener("eventThatUpdatesNavigator", updateNavi);
  }, [navigator])

  return navi;
}
```

Comment: But I am using `useState()` to capture that navigator already, can you show an example for that?

Comment: Edited. The reason it doesn't work right now is that React has no way to track navigator changing at all. You need an event listener of some sort.

Comment: Added an example. Hope it helps.

Comment: Ah right. I need to use an event for checking that. thank you!

Comment: After doing some researches, I found out that no event is responsible for the change of navigator? How should I implement it correctly then?